# An alignment problem arose while using `\shortintertext{}` command

Tags: equations, align, mathtools

Why is the first equation in the code below not centered? 
I want it to be centered like the second one. Could anyone kindly help me?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{align*}
f\wedge g = \frac{1}{k!\ell !}A(f\otimes g),
\shortintertext{or explicitly,}
\bigl(f\wedge g \bigr) \bigl(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+\ell} \bigr)
&=\frac{1}{k!\ell!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+\ell}}
\bigl(\text{sgn\,}\sigma  \bigr) 
\bigl(f\otimes g \bigr)
\bigl(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)}  \bigr)
  \\&= \frac{1}{k! \ell !} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+\ell}} 
\bigl(\text{sgn\,}\sigma \bigr) 
f\bigl(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k)}  \bigr)
g\bigl(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)} \bigr).
\end{align*}
```

and here is a screenshot of what latex produces

[image]

Comment: because you use align, but the first equation line hasn't any anchor to which it should be aligned. try add ampersand before equal sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

If you use `align` (or `align*`), than you need to use ampersands (`&`) to mark anchors to which the parts of equation should be aligned. In your example in the first equation it is missed.

Below are two cases: with `\shortintertext{...}` and with classic `\intertext` which gives to my test better result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
f\wedge g   
    & = \frac{1}{k!\ell !}A(f\otimes g),
    \shortintertext{or explicitly,}
\bigl(f\wedge g \bigr) \bigl(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+\ell} \bigr)
    & = \frac{1}{k!\,\ell!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+\ell}}\bigl(\text{sgn\,}\sigma \bigr)
        \bigl(f\otimes g \bigr)
        \bigl(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)} \bigr) \\
    &= \frac{1}{k!\,\ell !} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+\ell}}
        \bigl(\text{sgn\,}\sigma \bigr)
        f\bigl(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k)} \bigr)
        g\bigl(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)}\bigr).
    \end{align*}
    \begin{align*}
f\wedge g
    & = \frac{1}{k!\ell !}A(f\otimes g),
    \intertext{or explicitly,}
\bigl(f\wedge g \bigr) \bigl(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+\ell} \bigr)
    & = \frac{1}{k!\,\ell!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+\ell}}\bigl(\text{sgn\,}\sigma \bigr)
        \bigl(f\otimes g \bigr)
        \bigl(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)} \bigr) \\
    &= \frac{1}{k!\,\ell !} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+\ell}}
        \bigl(\text{sgn\,}\sigma \bigr)
        f\bigl(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k)} \bigr)
        g\bigl(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)}\bigr).
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

For strictly centered multi line equation is intended `gather` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{gather*}
f\wedge g  = \frac{1}{k!\ell !}A(f\otimes g),
    \shortintertext{or explicitly,}
    \begin{aligned}
\bigl(f\wedge g \bigr) \bigl(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+\ell} \bigr)
    & = \frac{1}{k!\,\ell!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+\ell}}\bigl(\text{sgn\,}\sigma \bigr)
        \bigl(f\otimes g \bigr)
        \bigl(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)} \bigr) \\
    &= \frac{1}{k!\,\ell !} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+\ell}}
        \bigl(\text{sgn\,}\sigma \bigr)
        f\bigl(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k)} \bigr)
        g\bigl(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)}\bigr).
    \end{aligned}
    \end{gather*}
 \end{document}
```

or simple (*edited*) but without use of `\intertext` as suggested egreg in his comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}5 <-- added

\begin{document}
    \[ % <-- first equation, can be written as `\begin{equation*}
f\wedge g  = \frac{1}{k!\ell !}A(f\otimes g),
    \]
or explicitly, % <-- moved into normal text
    \begin{align*} % <-- second equation
\bigl(f\wedge g \bigr) \bigl(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+\ell} \bigr)
    & = \frac{1}{k!\,\ell!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+\ell}}\bigl(\sgn \sigma \bigr)
        \bigl(f\otimes g \bigr)
        \bigl(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)} \bigr) \\
    &= \frac{1}{k!\,\ell !} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+\ell}}
        \bigl(\sgn \sigma \bigr)
        f\bigl(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k)} \bigr)
        g\bigl(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)}\bigr).
    \end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

which to opinion many people gives the best result among proposed solutions. *Note:* in the last example is added definition `\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}` and in equation instead of `\text{sgn\,}`   used shorter `\sgn`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, with additional space fractions look better. I correct my answer.

Comment: I used gather instead but I got the error `Missing $ inserted` @Zarko

Comment: probably you have ampersand in `gather`, but in it is not allowed ... :(. I will add example to my answer.

Comment: Actually, I like better the last way, but it should be `equation*` followed by normal text and then `align*`. By the way, you should use `\operatorname{sgn}`

Comment: Me to, but I followed OP question. Meanwhile Mico already show, how to do this .... regard operator name I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to providing the missing `&` alignment point in the first row and fixing a spacing issue around consecutive factorial terms -- see @Zarko's answer -- you may also want to take care of a handful of additional finer points of (math) typography.

- You appear to be using `sgn` as a math operator. Don't use `\text{sgn}\,` throughout the text; instead, provide the instruction `\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}` in the preamble and type `\sgn` in the body of the document.
- No need to type `\ldots`; type `\dots` and let LaTeX take care of the positioning of the ellipses.
- The use of `\bigl` and `\bigr` to size some of the parentheses seems unnecessary; in my view the equations look better if the parentheses appear in their basic size.
- Use `smashoperator[r]{\sum...}` to snug up the space between the summation symbols and the subsequent material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f\wedge g &= \frac{1}{k!\,\ell!}A(f\otimes g),
\intertext{or explicitly,}
(f\wedge g) (v_{1},\dots,v_{k+\ell})
&=\frac{1}{k!\,\ell!} \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+\ell}}}
(\sgn\sigma ) 
(f\otimes g)
(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)} ) \\
&= \frac{1}{k!\, \ell!} \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+\ell}}} 
(\sgn\sigma) 
f(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots, v_{\sigma(k)} )
g(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\dots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)})\,.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As @egreg has noted in a comment, the equation immediately above the "or, equivalently" interjection is quite separate from the remaining material; it may thus be preferable to simply center-set the first equation and use `align*` just for the remaining, two-line expression. (I can't do much about the OP's use of `\ell`. I used `\smashoperator[r]{...}` mainly to avoid creating an overfull line.) I.e., the following look may well be preferable:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\begin{document}
\[
f\wedge g = \frac{1}{k!\,\ell!}A(f\otimes g)\,,
\]
or explicitly,
\begin{align*}
(f\wedge g) (v_{1},\dots,v_{k+\ell})
&=\frac{1}{k!\,\ell!} \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+\ell}}}
(\sgn\sigma ) 
(f\otimes g)
(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)} ) \\
&= \frac{1}{k!\, \ell!} \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+\ell}}} 
(\sgn\sigma) 
f(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots, v_{\sigma(k)} )
g(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\dots, v_{\sigma(k+\ell)})\,.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion the first formula should be centered all the way, so `equation*`; no `\intertext` is needed as `align*` would follow. I'm a fan neither of `\ell`, to be honest, nor of `\smashoperator.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I've posted an addendum to show an alternate solution. (I used `\smashoperator` mainly to avoid creating an overfull line...)